Hall effect source impedance
Background
I am an electrical engineer. My friend is a technician in a physics lab and he is using an electromagnetic flow meter (i.e. magmeter) which relies on the Hall effect to measure the flow rate of a conductive fluid. He has been asking me about the electronic signal chain that measures the output of the Hall sensor, and I told him he needs to consider the output impedance of the sensor and the input impedance of whatever is connected to it.
The Quora thread linked below suggests that Hall sensors have a high output impedance,
https://www.quora.com/Why-is-a-high-input-impedance-device-generally-needed-to-measure-the-hall-voltage
, but the Stack Exchange answer linked below suggests it has a low output impedance.
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/275465/107412
Question
What dictates the output impedance of a Hall sensor?
My understanding is that the electric force behind the Hall voltage balances the Lorentz force. To try to understand the mechanism behind a finite output impedance, I considered what would happen if a short circuit was applied across the electrodes of a Hall sensor: the Hall voltage would be zero, and the magnetic field due to the current through the short would have to compensate the Lorentz force, but I do not understand how.
